# reescritura de campos Mysql o campos a null

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, null, godaddy

Tengo un hosting en Godaddy de espacio ilimitado con una base de datos en Mysql en MyISAM para mi aplicación. La bbdd tiene un peso de 280.4Mb y una de las tablas contiene 120713 registros.

Desde hace un tiempo algunos de estos campos de esta tabla se están cambiando a null o en otros casos los de tipo fecha cambian a una fecha distinta a la que debe ser, es decir, se reescriben a una fecha diferente.

Para llenar esta tabla utilizo un procedimiento que se ejecuta diariamente; sin embargo antes no he tenido este problema y es el mismo procedimiento que siempre se utiliza.

Alguna sugerencia de lo que puede estar pasando??.. Gracias.

Comment: intenta bajar la BBDD y hacer una prueba en tu local, con el script que mencionas, posterior a eso puedes compartirnos el Procedimiento almacenado para revisarlo.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, haré la prueba e informaré. Saludos

Comment: Tu proceso sólo añade campos o actualiza campos antiguos? El campo de fecha que dices no tendrá acaso una cláusula ON UPDATE CURRENT TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Hola amenadiel. También actualiza campos antiguos. Por ejemplo, tengo entre varios campos 2 qie son de tipo fecha. Uno es iniVigencia y otro finVigencia. Yo solo actualizo finVigencia, sin embargo, cuando reviso luego de unos dias estan cambiados un solo campo o ambos a la vez. A veces los pone en null y otras veces los cambia correlativamente, es decir, 2032-03-15, 2032-03-16, 2032-03-17 y así avanza el mes, dia y año. Solo me pasa con estos 2 campos que son fechas, los demás no cambian. Gracias.